# Converting Avro file to JSONs using JSONOutputer

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a requirement where I need to extract JSON files from Avro by using U-SQL. Avro files contain a collection of JSON and need to extract individual JSON from Avro. Here I have written code.
I used JsonOuptter() for writing jsons.

```
OUTPUT @source
TO "C:/Users/gutthil1/Desktop/ActivityTracker/Single_JSON/schemaType.json"
USING new JsonOutputter();
```

I am getting JSON as like below.

```
[
  {
    "type": "CE",
    "cnn": "11",
    "source": "{\r\n  \"vendorCd\": \"G\",\r\n  \"brandCd\": \"4\",\r\n  \"channelCd\": \"C\",\r\n  \"accessTypeCd\": \"I\"\r\n}",

  },
  {
    "type": "CE",
    "cnn": "9",
    "source": "{\r\n  \"vendorCd\": \"G\",\r\n  \"brandCd\": \"4\",\r\n  \"channelCd\": \"C\",\r\n  \"accessTypeCd\": \"I\"\r\n}",

  }
]
```

I am expecting JSON as like below.

```
[
{  
   "type":"CE",
   "ccn":"11",
   "source":{  
      "vendorCd":"G",
      "brandCd":"4",
      "channelCd":"C",
      "accessTypeCd":"I"
   },
{  
   "type":"CE",
   "ccn":"9",
   "source":{  
      "vendorCd":"G",
      "brandCd":"4",
      "channelCd":"C",
      "accessTypeCd":"I"
   }
]
```

Thanks for your help and support.

Answer (score 0):

Your `source` column is of type `string` and thus gets inlined as a string value and not a JSON object. You currently have the following two options, both probably requiring you to extend the JSONOutputter code:

1. Add an option that allows you to specify which columns should be inlined as a JSON fragment instead of a string.
2. Add an option to treat SqlMap as the property set for the column instead of string.